# How do I dynamically add an attribute to a module from within that module?

Tags: python

Say in a module I want to define:

```
a = 'a'
b = 'b'
...
z = 'z'
```

For some set (in this case I chose letters).  How do I dynamically set attributes on the current module?  Something like:

```
for letter in ['a', ..., 'z']:
    setattr(globals(), letter, letter)
```

This doesn't work, but what would?  (Also my understanding is that globals() within a module points to a dict of the attributes of that module, but feel free to correct me if that's wrong).

Comment: instead of typing out `'a', 'b' ... 'z'`, try this code instead: `[chr(a) for a in range(97, 123)]`, which will result in the same thing.

Comment: You can also try: `from string import lowercase as letters`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

globals() returns the dictionary of the current module, so you add items to it as you would to any other dictionary.  Try:

```
for letter in ['a', ..., 'z']:
    globals()[letter] = letter
```

or to eliminate the repeated call to globals():

```
global_dict = globals()
for letter in ['a', ..., 'z']:
    global_dict[letter] = letter
```

or even:

```
globals().update((l,l) for l in ['a', ...,'z'])
```